# print special characters like " as output to the terminal

Tags: python

I want to print a string which contains `"` in it. I need to use `row["column_name"]` also inside the print function. I have problem printing `"` in the middle of string

```
print("_:m"+str(row["movieId"])+" <release_year> "+str(row["release_year"])+"^^<datetime> .\n")
```

expected output is

```
_:m3  <release_year> "1995"^^<datetime> .
```

Comment: You should "escape it". Add inside a string `\ ` before each `"`, so python know that it should pass `"` as character, not as symbol of string end.

Answer (score 0):

You could use backslash followed by a quote

Print( ' \" ')

Output:

"

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the `"` or other chars with `\"` in print statement

```
>>> print("_:m" + "\"1995\"")
_:m"1995"
```

I hope this helps.

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals